# SSIS/SQL Automation

Tags: sql, ssis

My company is a direct mail company, and we are looking for ways to improve workflow as we continue to grow via automation with SSIS, SQL and Excel.

Basically, what we want to do is to be able for our processes to run automatically when we're not in the office. I.e. A file comes in, and, based on where the file is placed, the processes will begin and the tasks we need done will start.

We know what we want it to do, we just are struggling on where to begin or, more specifically, what is the best way to go about automating our services like that?

Comment: How many files / processes are you automating? Since you are struggling to work out where to begin I suggest your first task is to scope all of your _existing_ manual data flows. If you have way too many then focus on scoping all the data flows on a single business unit. If this is happening because of a particular pain point then pick a pain point to solve but if you are one of the few business interested in solving an IT issue **before** it occurs, scope it all first - understand the landscape and come up with a roadmap for attacking it.

Comment: Overall, we have thousands of files automating. Most use the same process, however. In fact, we'd only be doing about eight different types of processes depending on what type of file comes in.

Comment: From a technical perspective, a good approach is to come up with a logical folder structure that you can drop your files into, then use a for each file loop to loop through and import the files. After that the file gets moved to a 'failed' or 'imported' folder. So you have a queue structure set up in the file system and a package that is run say every five minutes to process the queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two general approaches: an event driven process or a polling process. The former runs when an event happens (file lands in a folder) while the latter runs on a periodic basis (every 5 minutes it looks to see if a file exists).

It is my experience that the event driven model sounds really good in practice but is horrible in implementation. We used a variety of off the shelf software and homegrown "file watcher" tasks to process data. Inevitably, *something* would happen and it wasn't registering the event so no data was being processed. The resolution was usually simple, restart the process and then move the files out and back again. Except we worked in a regulated environment where we didn't have access to move the files so that would take a different person to reset the queue versus who could move files about.

A polling process is much easier. If there's work to be done, it does so. Otherwise it goes back to sleep. Windows Task Scheduler can do this just fine. SQL Server has it's own job scheduling system called SQL Agent. It too can run packages at various intervals.

It might be tempting to have SSIS run in a infinite loop checking for files or using WMI events to try to catch a file being placed but don't do either of those. SSIS is not designed to be running all the time. Instead, use proven products to handle the stuff they were meant for.

Comment: My experience with the event-driven model mirrors yours.

Comment: Appreciate the help! Going to be sitting down with the team today to discuss more regarding our plans. The polling process sounds like a nice way to start.    
  
We are going to be creating eight different package/process templates that will be utilized based on the file that is in the folder. Would the polling process work for that?